# iTunes Connect: Your app "*" (Apple ID: *) has one or more issues -- email goes to entire user list, all test flight users, no matter what app

Tags: app-store-connect

Today I submitted a new test app to the app store, via Xcode, to be viewed in ItunesConnect.  The app submitted successfully, but the binary was rejected after about a minute by ITC.  There was a problem with the AppIcons having an alpha channel in the PNGs.  I get that a lot.

The the problem I noticed is that I was notified by email from ITC, and that email is sent to the entire User List for our entity.  This means all of your test flight users in ITC, for all our apps.  In order to add a test flight user, they need to be setup in Users&Roles, and are usually given an arbitrary role like "Sales/Marketing".  (why isn't there a role specifically for test flight users only?).  I try to turn notifications off for them, but the settings seem limited.

Finally, all these users are getting notifications for this new test app which they've never been associated and shouldn't care about.  TestFlight is not enabled for this app, but that seems irrelevant here.

Is there any way to stop the entire user list from getting technical email errors and such for entirely non-related apps?

I attempted to disable notifications in the sort of related notification section, but it is very vague and doesn't seem relevant.  It didn't help.
[image]

Comment: Similar problem here (with the "missing push notification") - all technical users are getting these notorious emails. Can it be stopped?

Comment: Did you find any solution? @roy650

Answer (score 4):

I received an email about my app's missing Push Notification Entitlement. In the original email all internal testers were listed.

I wanted to make sure only myself and developers were getting notifications like this going forward. Looking through the available documentation and even the Apple support line yielded no solutions, so I tried my luck at a few theories and found a fix.

Answer:

You need to change the roles of your internal testers to that of a non-technical user (I believe).

As I understand it, technical users as well as admins will receive the notifications in question.

I tested this out by changing all non-developers listed in my internal testers/itunes connect users list to the role of "Marketing".

Then I re-uploaded the build that triggered the original email. Once the new email was generated, I validated that the users I changed to a "Marketing" role were not included in the email list.

Hope this helps, good luck! :)