# iTunes Connect: Your app has one or more issues — email goes to entire user list

Tags: ios, email, app-store-connect, testflight

I received email from itunes connect (Apple staff) about an issue in one of my applications (Although that issue didn't exist [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32251123/missing-push-notification-entitlement/32283844#32283844))

The problem is that its email was sent to all the users with Admin, technical & App manager roles, which is quite bad.

Is there any way, we can disable such emails? I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32236225/4297260) thread on Stack overflow, but i guess there'll be some solution other than this

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like turning off the *App Status Reports* notifications for each user would work. The verbiage is kind of vague though.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Storm. My users are technical and all of these points are selected as "no territories" for them. Still they are recieving notifications.
i just want them to get email about beta testing, nothing else

Comment: @FayzaNawaz hmmmm. Pretty sure there's no other user settings except for the ones shown in my screenshot. I'd suggest contacting Apple directly.

Comment: @FayzaNawaz my pleasure. If you receive a helpful reply from Apple be sure to post it as an answer here.

Comment: Sure, i've also asked this question on apple developer forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/176890#176890